# Example for override function in Perl

Tags: perl, overriding

Could you please elaborate on override function in Perl. Some simple examples will be great to understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Overriding-Built-in-Functions

> Many built-in functions may be overridden, though this should be tried only occasionally and for good reason. Typically this might be done by a package attempting to emulate missing built-in functionality on a non-Unix system.
>
> Overriding may be done only by importing the name from a module at compile time--ordinary predeclaration isn't good enough. However, the use subs pragma lets you, in effect, predeclare subs via the import syntax, and these names may then override built-in ones:

Example:

```
use subs 'chdir', 'chroot', 'chmod', 'chown';
chdir $somewhere;
sub chdir { ... }
```

---

***Note:** all of the above was extracted from the above link*

Answer (score 5):

[perldoc CORE](http://perldoc.perl.org/CORE.html) shows a simple example of how to override the built-in [hex](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/hex.html) function.

```
   BEGIN {
       *CORE::GLOBAL::hex = sub { 1; };
   }

   print hex("0x50"),"\n";                     # prints 1
   print CORE::hex("0x50"),"\n";               # prints 80
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Sub::Override](http://p3rl.org/Sub%3a%3aOverride), but I don't know if it can override native functions.